# Replace last character of all columns dynamically in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with column names ending with integer. And I need to replace the integer part to month and year starting from a specific month to last 12 months. How to do it in a dynamic way.
Example could be:

```
columns = ['A_0','A_1','A_2','A_3','B_0','B_1','B_2', 'B_3'])
```

I want to achieve:

```
['A_OCT20','A_SEP20','A_AUG20','A_JUL20','B_OCT20','B_SEP20','B_AUG20','B_JUL20']
```

I am trying this

```
base_mon = "OCT20"

for i in range(4):
    curr_mon = pd.to_datetime('01'+base_mon, format='%d%b%y') - relativedelta(months=i)
    curr_mon_str2 = curr_mon.strftime('%b%y').upper()
    
    df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(str(i), curr_mon_str2)
```

but my output looks like this

```
 A_OCTAUG200  A_SEPAUG200  A_AUG20  A_JUL20  B_OCTAUG200  B_SEPAUG200 B_AUG20  B_JUL20
```

Could you please help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

```
# forming a base date for calculations
base_mon = "OCT20"
base_date = pd.to_datetime(base_mon, format="%b%y")

# to-be filled
new_columns = []

# for each column name...
for col in df.columns:
    # split into 3 parts: characters, underscore and digits
    name, _, digit = col.partition("_")

    # get the offseted month & year
    date = base - pd.DateOffset(months=int(digit))
    
    # add back the name (e.g., `"A"`), underscore and the new date
    new_col = name + "_" + date.strftime("%b%y").upper()

    # store in a list
    new_columns.append(new_col)

# change the original columns
df.columns = new_columns
```

```
>>> new_columns
["A_OCT20", "A_SEP20", "A_AUG20", "A_JUL20", "B_OCT20", "B_SEP20", "B_AUG20", "B_JUL20"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`import pandas as pd`

```
# Your columns
columns = ['A_0','A_1','A_2','A_3','B_0','B_1','B_2', 'B_3']
```

```
# First we generate the dates, and format it to your needs
dates = [x.strftime('%b').upper()+x.strftime('%y') for x in 
         pd.date_range('2019-11-01', '2020-11-01', freq='M')]
>>>['NOV19',
 'DEC19',
 'JAN20',
 'FEB20',
 'MAR20',
 'APR20',
 'MAY20',
 'JUN20',
 'JUL20',
 'AUG20',
 'SEP20',
 'OCT20']

# Then we create a lookup
lookup = {str(idx):date for (idx, date) in zip(range(11, -1, -1), dates)}
>>> {'11': 'NOV19',
 '10': 'DEC19',
 '9': 'JAN20',
 '8': 'FEB20',
 '7': 'MAR20',
 '6': 'APR20',
 '5': 'MAY20',
 '4': 'JUN20',
 '3': 'JUL20',
 '2': 'AUG20',
 '1': 'SEP20',
 '0': 'OCT20'}
```

```
# Then we replace the values in your column names
replaced_columns = [x.split('_')[0]+'_'+lookup[x.split('_')[-1]] for x in columns]
>>>['A_OCT20',
 'A_SEP20',
 'A_AUG20',
 'A_JUL20',
 'B_OCT20',
 'B_SEP20',
 'B_AUG20',
 'B_JUL20']
```

After that you can just replace the columns in your data frame

```
df.columns = replaced_columns
```